# How do professors and teachers develop critical thinking?

Tags: research-process, teaching

I'm in medical school and I am always puzzled by professors and teachers, specifically Sal from Khan Academy, due to how they can deeply understand the subjects and can understand anything. It's like they have a secret formula or way of thinking about information.

In my attempts to answer this I came to the conclusion that they have critical thinking and reading skills that I don't have and I reached this conclusion after reading a little of the book *"Reading Critically, Writing well."*

Am I correct in this and if I am how can I develop my critical thinking?

In addition, I think that these people have good research skills so any recommendation for that will be useful.

Comment: But just to comment one thing that you are missing that these professors have and you don't have: they have several years of experience. You should not expect to have the same level of critical thinking and teaching skills of a professor when you are in your third year at the university. :) For me much of the critical thinking I developed was not due to reading, but because I was challenged in many different ways by many clever people along the years.

Comment: Similar to what @TheDoctor comments: experience. My joke to my students is that one of the main impediments of inexperienced people is failing to understand the benefits of experience. :)  Also known as "hindsight". :)

Comment: @paulgarrett: Also: Good Judgement comes from experience. Experience comes from Bad Judgement. (Attr: Rita Mae Brown)

Comment: I hope your time in medical school will help you develop your critical thinking skills!

Comment: Having a solid understanding of a pre-existing body of knowledge does not necessarily have much to do with critical thinking. Just because someone excels in their subfield (particularly in matters not involving their own original research), that does not necessarily mean that they are able to critically evaluate their beliefs. I would imagine that what you are probably missing is subject-specific knowledge plus possibly some general problem solving skills.

Comment: Why do you think they're so brilliant? They might be, chances are they're not. You've been watching videos and hearing lectures about stuff that was textbook knowledge when the grandfathers of those guys were students. Thousands of professors have been teaching that, some good, some badly, and millions of students have learned it, some better than others.

Comment: Narrow your post to remove multiple questions (am I correct that professionals display deep knowledge because they know how to do critical thinking, how can I learn to do critical thinking, how can I improve my research skills). As suggestions: the first question demands your own critical thinking to answer for your own satisfaction, and the third question is rather too broad to address properly.

Answer (score 2):

What is critical thinking to you?

Let's call it the ability to dissect a problem or question in ways that allow you to assure that a given answer is complete, where complete means not only correct but also adequate and proper.

With this definition, I suggest critical thinking is engaged in the first three steps in problem solving: define the problem, gather the information about it, and propose solutionS to it. The first step disassembles the problem statement to every possible variation on meaning. Pictures (being worth thousands of words) help. The second step clarifies what is and is not known before starting to solve the problem. The third step step goes through logical assertions and assumptions to try to to reach a closed-form conclusion. I purposely capitalized the S on solutionS to indicate not just one but many possible answers may be proposed.

Critical thinking is the iterative process of going through the problem definition, information, assumptions, and assertions to form a self-consistent, satisfactory conclusion for what a problem means, what it has at hand, and how it could be solved. The goal at the end is to be able to stand at a mirror and say "I am fully convinced that this proposed solution is fully justified, is properly framed, and can provide a complete result!" If you cannot do this, go back and figure out why not. And when you can do this, go back and vary something ... the given information, an assumption, or an assertion. How does making this change propagate through the iterative steps of defining, gathering, and proposing? Can you still end with a complete solution even after you have made the change? Why or why not?

On hand a chosen approach, the concluding two steps to problem solving are to evaluate the approach and to report a final answer. These two steps do not engage critical thinking. We can essentially delegate them to technicians or robots or calculators.

In summary, following the first three steps in problem solving can serve to discipline you on how to think critically.

Answer (score -1):

Most universities will have a course, perhaps in the philosophy department, perhaps a course in philosophical logic there that covers this. In the US, many of us took some philosophy as part of an undergraduate program.

One aspect of critical thinking in the sciences, and perhaps medicine, is developing the ability to evaluate the validity of evidence given for claims and hypotheses. Some of that is statistical in nature and is usually taught as part of a course in conducting research in the various fields.

A good starting place is at [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Critical_thinking) which has a good discussion and an extensive bibliography.

Another easy resource is a search for Critical Thinking at Amazon.

There are likely online courses as well for those so inclined.

Critical thinking is a lot about recognizing fallacies. Like any skill it takes practice. Some of the books have exercises, actually.